# Javabeans can not persistent input data

Tags: java, user-interface, javabeans

I faced a problem that the typed data can not be persistent. I　want to store java Swing GUI to XML file and reuse them latter. Now I store the GUI successfully. But after I type some data into the textfield. The typed data can not be encoded into XML file. Could you help me store both the GUI and the typed content? Below is the code using javabeans XMLencoder:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class ResourceName extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
static JFileChooser chooser;
JButton save,load;
JTextField  tf; 
static JFrame frame;
 public ResourceName(){

     chooser = new JFileChooser();
     chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));

     frame = new JFrame("ResourceName");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     save = new JButton("Save");
     save.setActionCommand("Save");
     save.addActionListener(this);

     load = new JButton("Load");
     load.setActionCommand("Load");
     load.addActionListener(this);
     tf = new JTextField(10);

     frame.add(save);
     frame.add(tf);
     frame.add(load);       

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

      if((e.getActionCommand()).equals("Save"))
      {
          save();
      }else if((e.getActionCommand()).equals("Load"))
      {
          load();
      }
  }


 public void save()
{
    if(chooser.showSaveDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try{
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream(file));
            encoder.writeObject(frame);
            encoder.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
  public void load()
{
    //show file chooser dialog
    int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    // if file selected, open
    if(r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try
        {
          File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
          XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new FileInputStream(file));
          decoder.readObject();
          decoder.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ResourceName test = new ResourceName();

}
}
```

Please help me solve this problem. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it may be that the `text` property, is `transient`, this means it won't be saved to the output automatically, by an `ObjectOutputStream`. You'll probably have to explicitly write that field.